# Adding FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I drag/drop facebooksdk.framework to my project(and i select copy items). I complete coded part and when i run my project it worked without any problem.

However when i close xCode and start xCode and run my project x code gives red error messages. Its;

```
"/Users/me/Desktop/xcode/swift/projects/projects/projects/projects-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found"
```

and other one is;

```
"Failed to import bridging header '/Users/me/Desktop/xcode/swift/projects/projects/projects/projects-Bridging-Header.h'
```

The problem solved by re-added facebooksdk.framework file to my project. Did i have to always add this framework to my project(everytime i start this project xcode gives red errors)? Is there any way to fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your `facebooksdk.framework` like this one inside `projects-Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```